# Is it possible to edit the text size of shortcode outputs from within admin?

Tags: theming

I'm using Drupal 7, and I have a carousel that uses shortcodes to output text.

[testimonial name="Angela Somone" sequence = "3"] My daughter attended the...

It would be good If I could adjust the text size of "Angela Somone" from within my admin panel without having to edit my css files and upload via GIT etc.

I tried wrapping it in a span but that breaks my code.